# What's the difference between "#@{var}" and "@#{var}" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I am quite new to Ruby and always assumed these two notations were an identical way to interpolate instance variables until I noticed the difference in the example code below for the 'vendor' parameter.

```
class Component
    def  initialize(name, version)
         @vendor = "vendor"
         @name = name
         @version = version
         puts  "#{@vendor}-@#{name}-@#{version}" 
    end 
end

ConfiguredComponent.new("param1", "param2")
```

=> this works

```
class Component
    def  initialize(name, version)
         @vendor = "vendor"
         @name = name
         @version = version
         puts  "@#{vendor}-@#{name}-@#{version}" 
    end 
end

ConfiguredComponent.new("param1", "param2")
```

=> using @#{vendor} notation does't work => **:in 'initialize': undefined local variable or method `vendor' for # (NameError)**

```
  class Component
     def  initialize(name, version)
        @vendor = "vendor"
        @name = name
        @version = version
        puts  "#{@vendor}-#{@name}-#{@version}" 
     end 
  end

  Component.new("param1", "param2")
```

=> this also works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the `#{(expression)}` that's significant.

If the expression is `#{name}` then that's substituting the variable `name` which in all your examples comes from the parameters input into the method.

If the expression is `#{@name}` then that's substituting the variable `@name` which is defined in the fourth line of your methods.

`@#{name}` is not a special construct. It's just the string `@` followed by the contents of the variable `name`.

The reason it didn't work in your second example is that you simply haven't defined a variable `vendor`.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here are all the examples I could think of :

```
@a = "hello"

strings =[ 
  "@a world",
  "@{a} world",
  "#a world",
  "#{@a} world",
  "#@a world",
  "#@aworld", # ! Will not output anything (no space after "@a", and @aworld isn't defined ) !
  "@#{@a} world"
]

puts strings
```

It outputs :

```
@a world
@{a} world
#a world
hello world
hello world

@hello world
```

But :

```
puts "@#{a} world"
```

throws an exception :

```
undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

`a` needs to be a defined variable or a method :

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a

  def greetings
    puts "#{a} world"
  end
end

t   = Test.new
t.a = "hello"
t.greetings # hello world
```

Comment: Wow, did not know about "#@a " interpolation, but figured out why it could be unintuitive (included it in your example).

Comment: Yes, I think "#@a" is mostly used in bugs :)